# How to test IO issues in Java?

Tags: java, unit-testing, io

How can I test behavior of my application code for the case of very bad IO performance without using mock streams that sleep (because they would react to interrupts)?

For instance, I want to test a `ConcurrentWrapper` utility that has a pool of threads for file IO. It submits each operation to an `ExecutorService` with `invokeAll()` with timeout. I want to confirm not only that the call with `ConcurrentWrapper` exits before timeout, but also that it somehow made the thread of its inner `ExecutorService` terminate (to avoid leakage).

I need to somehow simulate slow IO in the inner thread, but in a way that will ignore interrupts (like real IO does).

**A bit of clarification**: No answer like "sleep and swallow `InterruptedException`" or "sleep, catch `InterruptedException` and go back to sleep" is acceptable. I want to test how my code handles interrupts and such instrumentation would defeat the purpose by handling them itself.

Comment: Have it sleep for some specified amount of time, and if it's woken early, go back to sleep?

Comment: So you want a thread that blocks (simulating slow IO), then throws an interrupted exception but keeps on blocking (simulating IO that continues executing)? This doesn't make a lot of sense. As time goes on, a method call either blocks, returns, or throws an exception; it can't do two out of three. Can you be clearer on what you want to accomplish?

Comment: I described the use case in the second paragraph - writing test for a wrapper/helper that limits duration of a call, verifying not only that the call finishes, but also that it does not leak in the inner pool by leaving the task still running in background thread.

Answer (score 1):

You can sleep in a way that will insist on sleeping through interrupts:

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
long end = start + sleepTime;
for (long now = start; now < end; now = System.currentTimeMillis()) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(end - now);
    } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
    }
}
```

Comment: In case I was not clear enough, take a look at updated question. I want to test how my code handles interruptions, so the instrumentation must ignore them completely. Silent swallowing is not unobtrusive enough.

Answer (score 0):

For testing with timeouts, you can actually put a maximum time to execute the test, in [JUnit](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Test.html) you can include the annotation timeout:

```
@Test(timeout=100)
public void method_withTimeout() {
       while(true);
}
```

For the part of testing that the method exits, you could use the [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) interface that provides a timeout for getting the results.

Comment: And how does this simulate slow IO?

Comment: About the slow IO, one non-optimal possibility would be to substitute the sleep between sending pieces of data with computation.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly, ReentrantLock might help.

```
final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

Callable<Void> c = new Callable<Void>() {
  public void call() {
    lock.lock();

    try {

       if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
         ...
       }
    }
    finally {
      lock.unlock();
    }
  }
}

// Submit to the pool
Future<Void> future = executorService.submit(c);

// you might want to sleep a bit to give the pool a chance
// to pull off the queue.

// Issue a cancel
future.cancel();

// Now release the lock, which should let your
// callable continue onto to the interrupted check.
lock.unlock();
```

Note that the "lock" method does not throw any InterruptedException (though there is a method for that called "lockInterruptibly"), and if you look at the code for that class, it's not catching and swallowing (as you've stated would not be what you want).